# NLog.config is not loaded in asp.net core 2.1 project?

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following NLog.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="On" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And then i have followed the following [tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)
But i replaced

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
        .Build();
```

with

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog();
```

But nothing is written to the specified file or the internal log no matter what i do.

I have also tried to quickwatch `NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config")` and it seems no rules or targets are loaded?

[image]

I have also verified that nlog.config exists in the build directory `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\` and as the right content.

I have also tried to put the absolute path to the file in the `NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog` but that didn't help.

Comment: Try to enable the internal logger via the API before creating the first Logger. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging (Then you can see where it searches for NLog.config). Remember to use NLog 4.5.9

Comment: Btw. `internalLogLevel="on"` should be `internalLogLevel="Trace"`. Try adding the option `throwConfigExceptions="true"` next to `throwExceptions="false"`

Comment: Thanks Rolf that could be the cause!

Comment: Well that did it @RolfKristensen if you create a answer ill mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`internalLogLevel="on"` should be `internalLogLevel="Trace"`.

You can add the option `throwConfigExceptions="true"` next to `throwExceptions="false"`. It will help you track down errors in the NLog.config. It is actually a good idea to have `throwConfigExceptions="true"` even when in production environments (Unlike `throwExceptions="true"`, which should only be used for unit-testing of NLog)